# What are these "lines" on the A319 flaps, are they damaged?

Tags: airliner, wing, aircraft-maintenance, airbus-a320, flaps

I've noticed a grey line on the flaps of the A319:

[image]

What is that?
[Source](http://www.airliners.net/photo/Northwest-Airlines/Airbus-A319-114/1155164/&sid=0e373b27976ef8bee7c8e931e517ce10)

Comment: duct tape holding the flap together ;-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are seeing the steel reinforcing sheet metal at the line where the spoilers rest on the flaps when both are retracted.  It is there as a bearing surface since there is some inevitable contact between the spoilers and the top surface of the flap when they are both retracted during flight.

Comment: From a maintenance point of view, do you known how long they are used before the sheet are changed?

Comment: I don't know if they have a regular maintenance schedule or wear limit on that sheet metal.

Comment: The technical name is Rubbing Strips.

Comment: If you painted those strips the paint would rub off unevenly and look like damage.